# Iterate <div> inside <ul> tag Java - Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup, java-11

I'm trying to get all `<div>` inside a `<ul>` tag using jsoup.

This is the HTML

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Try jsoup</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <ul class="product__listing product__grid">
         <div class="product-item">
            <div class="content-thumb_gridpage">
               <a class="thumb" href="index1.html" title="Tittle 1">
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="product-item">
            <div class="content-thumb_gridpage">
               <a class="thumb" href="index2.html" title="Tittle 2">
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="product-item">
            <div class="content-thumb_gridpage">
               <a class="thumb" href="index3.html" title="Tittle 3">
            </div>
         </div>
      </ul>
   </body>
</html>
```

What I'm trying to iterate is all `<div class="product-item">` so then I can add to a list all `<a class="thumb">` properties

```
List-product-details
[0] href="index1.html" title="Tittle 1"
[1] href="index2.html" title="Tittle 2"
[2] href="index3.html" title="Tittle 3"
```

Note that there can be 'N' `product-item` div

Here is What I got so far:

```
Elements productList = sneakerList.select("ul.product__listing product__grid");
    Elements product = productList.select("ul.product-item");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < product.size(); i++) {
        Elements productInfo = product.get(i).select("div.product-item").select("div.content-thumb_gridpage").select("a.thumb");
        System.out.format("%s %s %s\n", productInfo.attr("title"), productInfo.attr("href"), productInfo.text());     
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try debugging line by line and checking at which line your code doesn't do what you expect?
I see two mistakes.

1. The first selector `"ul.product__listing product__grid"` contains a space. Now it means: find element `ul` with class `product__listing` and inside search for element `<product__grid> </product__grid>`. You probably meant: select element `ul` having class `product__listing` and having class `product__grid`. You have to use dot `.` before second class name and remove space to look at the same level. So correct selector will be: `"ul.product__listing.product__grid"`.
2. Second selector you're using is `"ul.product-item"`. It will return empty result. That's because you're already inside `ul` and you're searching for another `ul`. Selector should be relative to where you are so using only `".product-item"` will be enough.

And now I get the ouput:

```
Tittle 1 index1.html
Tittle 2 index2.html 
Tittle 3 index3.html
```